# Printer DLL gets loaded/unloaded many times when accessing PageSettings from within a mixed-mode application

Tags: c#, printing, mixed-mode

```
var settings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "Landscape: " + settings.Landscape );
```

When I run this code in a managed application, everything is OK. However, in a mixed-mode (C# & C++) application, when accessing the `Landscape` property (or any other property of the `settings` object), the printer driver DLL gets loaded and unloaded many times which causes the code to be significantly slower than in the managed application. The output contains dozens of lines like these:

```
Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\EP0LUZ00.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
Unloaded 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\drivers\w32x86\3\EP0LUZ00.DLL'
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent such "wasting"?